# How to accommodate two boxes in CSS

Tags: css

first, im very new to CSS, trying to learn it and understand it. I have blown my brains out trying to figure out how to get the little selected box with the feeds, facebook and twitter icons to the top, where it should go, just beside the school logo. Can you please help me put the selected box a little bit more up? Thanks. Please check the link, image inside, stack won't let me upload pictures.

http://cl.ly/3cyt

Here is the code.

```
#header #inner {
    float: left;
    width: 960px;
    clear: both;
}
    #header #logo {
        height: 99px;
        clear: both;
        width: 730px;
        float: left;
}
    #header #inner #logo #pandecta-logo {
    float: left;
}
    #header #inner #logo #eld-logo {
    float: right;
}
    #header #inner #logo a {
        position: relative;
        top: -22px;
#header #inner #right {
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
}
```

"#right" is the twitter,facebook,feeds box.

Here its the HTML

```
    <div id="inner">
        <!-- Logo -->
        <div id="logo">
            <a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/">
                <?php if (strlen($wpzoom_misc_logo_path) > 1) { ?>
                    <div id="pandecta-logo">
                    <img src="<?php echo "$wpzoom_misc_logo_path";?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" />
                    </div>
                <?php } else { ?><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/logo.png" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" /><?php } ?>
                <div id=eld-logo>
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/eld.png" alt="Logo Escuela Libre de Derecho" />
                </div>
            </a>
        </div> 
        <div id="head_banner">
            <?php if (strlen($wpzoom_ad_head_imgpath) > 1 && $wpzoom_ad_head_select == 'Yes') {?>
                 <?php if (strlen($wpzoom_ad_head_imgpath) > 1) { echo stripslashes($wpzoom_ad_head_imgpath); }?> 
            <?php } ?>

        </div>

        <div id="right">
            <div id="social">
                <ul>
                    <?php if (strlen($wpzoom_twitter) > 0) { ?><li class="button"><a href="http://twitter.com/<?php echo $wpzoom_twitter; ?>" title="<?php echo"$wpzoom_twitter_heading"; ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/icons/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" /></a></li><?php } ?>

                    <?php if (strlen($wpzoom_facebook) > 0) { ?><li class="button"><a href="<?php echo $wpzoom_facebook; ?>" title="<?php echo"$wpzoom_facebook_heading"; ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/icons/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" /></a></li><?php } ?>

                    <?php if (strlen($wpzoom_rssicon) > 0) { ?><li class="button"><a href="<?php echo $wpzoom_rssicon; ?>" title="<?php echo"$wpzoom_rssicon_heading"; ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/icons/rss.png" alt="RSS" /></a></li><?php } ?>

                </ul>
            </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: You're asking for trouble down the line nesting all those IDs. Would you mind posting your html as well? Off the top of my head you'll probably need to clear your floats (<br clear="both">) and possibly adjust widths.

Comment: id's are, by definition, unique: simplify your selectors, or use classes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `float: left` to **#logo** and **#headbanner**
2. Add `float: right` to **#right**
3. To whatever comes after #header, add `clear: both`: it makes sure that the main content positions itself AFTER anything you've floated left or right before instead of overlapping it.

Also, as zzzzBoy said, no need to mention every ID in the rules (e.g. #header #inner #logo #pandecta-logo). You could just reference it via the final ID (#pandecta-logo), since IDs are unique and you cannot use them elsewhere on the same document anyway.